# What could "kn." abbreviation stand for?

Tags: non-native-speaker, скорочення

Chuzhynoiu: kn. VII  describes an edition of a book by Oleksandr Oles'.

1. What does *kn.* mean?
2. is there an online list of Ukrainian abbreviations where I could have found this?

Comment: Welcome to Ukrainian Language! Please provide with some citation for context. You must have been reading a translation, and abbreviations are basically up to the will of the translator. For example "kn" could stand for книга `/knyha/` ("a book"), but it could be "volume", "section", or anything else.

Answer (score 8):

> is there an online list of Ukrainian abbreviations where I could have found this?

For example: http://abbrs.info/

> [Chuzhynoiu: kn. VII](https://diasporiana.org.ua/poeziya/2004-oles-o-chuzhinoyu-kn-vii/) describes an edition of a book by Oleksandr Oles'.
>
> What does kn. mean?

It means *knyha* (book):

> кн. книга

Answer (score 0):

kn. stands for "книга" (book), and in this context refers to volume (like in a "Random Dictionary, Vol. IV".

Comment: Welcome to Ukrainian Language! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to back it with references to credible sources and/or academic research. Unbacked posts attract downvotes and disputes. Also, your answer seems to add nothing comparing to the existing answer.

Comment: It adds a comparison of "kn." to "vol.", and analogies usually help to understand something better. Besides, in a question as mundane as this I am not sure what kind of reference can be used.